# Problems with Git using C# and ASP.Net with Rider and Visual Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, git

Me and my two group members are having a lot of trouble. Honestly i don't know what the error is because i don't really understand the problem honestly.

My colleague made a new 'ASP .NET Core Web Application' in Rider on her Macbook.
She then connected that project with Github and i cloned it in Visual Studio.
Visual Studio then tells me i have changes to commit.

My problem is i don't know what these changes are or why they appear since i would expect there to be no changes, after all i didn't change anything.

Can one of you explain why the changes happen, what kind of changes it is, and how i resolve the situation so we can work on the project together?

Here is a picture containing the changes that Visual Studio tells me i can commit.

[image]

If i need to provide more information please tell me so and i will do in a heartbeat :)

Bear in mind that i am new to using both .NET and ASP.

Comment: Please include the picture in the post, not just a link

Comment: try in a command prompt cmd or powershell or gitbash (did you install git for windows?) git status ti see what are the files affected by the change

Comment: You need to use a `.gitignore` file for Visual Studio, when creating a new repository in GitHub you are presented with various predefined `.gitignore` setups.

Comment: Exclude build generated files and for the other files, perhaps you should have eol problems also and you think about adding a `.gitattributes` to manage it. See https://help.github.com/en/articles/dealing-with-line-endings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those files are the `bin` and `obj` folders, which are build output. Because they are build output, they will change every time a build is run and **should not be checked in**.

The other folder is the `.vs` folder which holds data individual to your computer about your preferences, settings, and a few other things relating to that solution. It also should not be checked in.

Just delete them from your repo, and add the folders to the .gitignore file.